# Filtro de Pesquisa mostrando somente 10 resultados

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, filtro, taxonomia

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um website em Wordpress, com um template comprado e estou com uma dificuldade que, acredito ser uma dúvida sobre o Wordpress e não sobre o tema.
O Website mostra varios estabelecimentos e, quando faço uma pesquisa, deveria me mostrar todos os estabelecimentos, porém neste caso me mostra somente 10 e, caso eu queira visualizar mais, preciso apertar no botão CARREGAR MAIS ESTABELECIMENTOS, algo que eu não gostaria de fazer e, como ele mostra 4 estabelecimentos por vez, acaba quebrando o layout, ficando sempre com 2 lugares vazios na terceira fileira (Como mostro nas imagens abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de mostrar todos os estabelecimentos, acredito que preciso mostrar para o wordpress que quero trazer todos, ou seja, um posts_per_page = -1, porém a forma que se mostra os estabelecimentos é via shortcode, segue abaixo:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;                
    $shortcode = '[jobs show_tags="true" orderby="rand"]';
    echo do_shortcode(  $shortcode );
?>
```

No shortcode já tentei inserir o posts_per_page mas não foi possível, ainda parecendo que existe em alguma outra parte uma seleção, porém no mesmo código foi possível trocar o orderby.

Gostaria de saber se tem algo a mais que posso fazer para que no shortcode ou de outra forma, possa mostrar todos os estabelecimentos sem necessidade de mostrar um número fixo.

Segue o link da página que estou falando: http://app.liveclube.com/descubra

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você usa algum plugin WP pra exibir esses posts ?

Comment: Olá LLima, não, tudo via código, mas acabei de achar a solução, havia um campo para inserção do total de posts a serem inseridos de uma só vez e funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser alterado em Configurações>Leitura.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, é exatamente isso porém pela configuração do custom post type.